# Array.ConvertAll не работает

Tags: c#

Цель программы - разбить введенное число на цифры.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        short[]num = Array.ConvertAll<char, Int16>
            (Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray(), Int16.Parse);
    }
}
```

Буду честен - в упор не понимаю почему ошибка.
Сами ошибки:

1) Наиболее подходящий перегруженный метод для "System.Array.ConvertAll(char[], System.Converter)" имеет несколько недопустимых аргументов (CS1502)

2) Аргумент "2": преобразование типа из "группа методов" в "System.Converter" невозможно (CS1503)

Короче - покажите как надо.

UPD:

**Решение нашел сам:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<byte> nums=new List<byte>();
        foreach (char c in Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray())
            nums.Add((byte)Char.GetNumericValue(c));
    }
}
```

Comment: Что-то в ответах никто не объяснил, почему код не работает. Придётся мне отдуваться. Метод `Int16.Parse` ждет на входе тип `string`, а ему подаётся `char`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, стоило ответом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string s = Console.ReadLine();
        short[] num = new short[s.Length];
        for(var i = 0; i < s.Length; i++) {
            num[i] = (short)Char.GetNumericValue(s[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за идею. Мой конечный код в вопросе, если интересно.

Comment: А за что минус поставили? ответ же правильный.

Comment: Мое мнение на этом портале вообще не учитывается) Так что минусы я не могу ставить.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char[] chars = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();
    short[] nums = Array.ConvertAll(chars, new Converter<char, Int16>(CharToShort));
    Array.ForEach(nums, n => Console.WriteLine(n));

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static short CharToShort(char input)
{
    Int16.TryParse(input.ToString(), out short result);

    return result;
}
```